# Jquery change() not working when Textarea value updated programmatically

Tags: jquery

How i can check if my textarea value changed when it's value changed programmatically?
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
#1<textarea id="txt1"></textarea><br>
#2<textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#txt2").live("keyup", function () {
    $("#txt1").text($("#txt2").val())
});

// not working
$("#txt1").live("input change propertychange", function () {
    alert('changed');
});
// not working
$('#txt1').change(function () {
    alert('changed');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wvmuzvq0/)

Also i can't change `TextArea#2` codes to add triggers etc.

**UPDATE**

Ok, Now i using Jquery 1.7.2 and replaced `.live` with `.on` but problem not fixed!
Please note my mean is when you typing in Textarea#2 the message "changed" mush shown because Textarea#1 value changed.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wvmuzvq0/2/)

Comment: .live() has been deprecated.  Look up .on() instead http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: .live() is deprecated  for jQuery1.7 n so on.. Make sure you are using the correct version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Translation: replace `.live(...` with `.on(...` and it should fix the problem.

**Edit:**

I see your fiddle is set to jQuery 1.6.4.  Unless you can upgrade, use `.delegate()` which isn't a straight substitution.